# How can I tidy up this servlet parameter check code?

Tags: java, servlets

One of the servlet in my web app takes parameters in the form `www.service.com/servletname/parameter1/parameter2`.

The first parameter is required and the second parameter is an integer. 
I've made some code to validate the parameters but it looks really really messy. Is there a nicer and cleaner way I can write the following:

Thanks :)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    resp.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    int maximumResults = defaultMaxResults;

    // check that parameters were provided
    if (req.getPathInfo() == null)
    {
       out.println( JSONHelper.writeStatus(false, Status.TOO_FEW_ARGS.getMessage()));
        return;
    }

    // seperate parameters
    String[] parameters = req.getPathInfo().split(PARAMETER_SEPERATOR);

    if (parameters.length < MIN_NUM_PARAMETERS)
    {
        out.println( JSONHelper.writeStatus(false, Status.TOO_FEW_ARGS.getMessage()));
        return;
    }

    // validate parameters
    if (parameters.length > MIN_NUM_PARAMETERS)
    {
        try
        {
        maximumResults = Integer.parseInt(parameters[2]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
        out.println( JSONHelper.writeStatus(false, Status.INVALID_MAX_RESULTS.getMessage()));
        return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you could use the Regex to solve this

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    resp.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    int maximumResults = defaultMaxResults;

    // you could create pathPattern as a Class field
    Pattern pathPattern = Pattern.compile("http://www.hostname.com/servletname/([^/]+)(/(\\d+))?$");

    Matcher m = pathPattern.matcher(req.getPathInfo());
    if(m.find()) {
         String param1 = m.group(1);
         String param2 = m.group(2); // NOTE param2 may be null
         // TODO your business here
         return;
    } else {
         // TODO throw your exception here
    }

}
```

You can change the pathPattern to meet your need. Hope this help. Feel free to response.

Comment: It's a viable solution but I'd like to quote: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.` I think it's a little too much to check parameters.

Comment: That's right, but I think this regexp is simple enough for you to test, it is not a real problem here.
Is your second parameter required too? If not, you can change the regexp to `http://www.hostname.com/servletname/([^/]+)/(\\d+)$`, you have **one** check now.

Comment: Your code worked perfect. I used it with another page and got the regex wrong which was a bit of a hassle. In the end, I'd prefer something that's easy to read though I do think your answer is a valid way of cleaning up the code.